# How to make an unique number from three other numbers?

Tags: hashcode

I have three numbers: N, M and D and I am told that:

> N * M * D <= 5,200,000

but also that

> N <= 1000, M <= 1000, D <= 200

so I can't declare an array of size `[1000][1000][200]`. I would want to declare instead an array of size 5,200,000 and determine an unique ID for each N,M,D.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: why you could declare an array of 1000 1000 200? what programming language you use?

Comment: I have limited memory of 64 MB

Comment: which programming language you use?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `N`, `M` and `D` are all `>= 0`,

```
((N * 1001) + M) * 1001 + D
```

should be collision-free.

Answer (score 0):

So they can be represented in 10 bits (or less), so why not (D<<20)|(M<<10)|(N) ?  It'll fit in a 32-bit integer, so that's nice.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question, fitting the limit of 5,200,000 integers.

Let a-b-c be the three numbers we want to make an unique value from and n-m-d be their limits ( a<=n, b<=m, c<=d). Each number from a-b-c will represent a digit from a different base and our goal is to convert this number to decimal.

> unique value = c  +  (b * d)  +  (a * m * d)

Let K be the unique value and we want to get the states which K represents (a,b,c)

> c=K%d;
>
> K/=d;
>
> b=K%m;
>
> K/=m;
>
> a=K;